# More pythonic way to replace empty strings in all dataframe except one column

Tags: python, pandas

Example dataframe only -

```
data = {'Header One' : ['  ','assda','thisisatest','20230606'],
    'Header Two' : ['xx ','hahah','thisistest','20230706'],
    'Header Three' : ['  ','a--s==sda',' is a test','20230603'],
    'Header Four': [' xx2', '\n', 'thisiatest', '20230609']}
```

I can replace the 'empty' values in this dataframe using

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
for col in df.loc[:, df.columns != "Header Two"]:
    df[col].replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan,regex=True,inplace=True)
```

However, I would prefer to be able to do this without the loop but do not seem to be able to figure out how or if this is possible.

I have tried using concat with a drop and replace but this doesn't seem to have the desired results.

```
pd.concat([df.pop('Header Two'), df.replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan,regex=True,inplace=True)])
```

Comment: Try `df.loc[:, df.columns != "Header Two"].replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan,regex=True,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) on the columns, and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Header Two'])
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
    Header One  Header Two Header Three Header Four
0          NaN         xx           NaN         xx2
1        assda       hahah    a--s==sda         NaN
2  thisisatest  thisistest    is a test  thisiatest
3     20230606    20230706     20230603    20230609
```

Comment: This is a nice answer and very specific and easy to debug. Well done !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to, first, create your columns and then filter your df.

```
columns = [col for col in data.columns if col != 'Header two']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns).replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan,regex=True)
```

Or, since you created the dataframe first.

```
data = {'Header One' : ['  ','assda','thisisatest','20230606'],
    'Header Two' : ['xx ','hahah','thisistest','20230706'],
    'Header Three' : ['  ','a--s==sda',' is a test','20230603'],
    'Header Four': [' xx2', '\n', 'thisiatest', '20230609']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


columns = [col for col in data.columns if col != 'Header two']
df = df[columns].replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan,regex=True)
```